# Should I always use __builtin_extract_return_addr after __builtin_return_address

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-extensions

[The gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html):

> Additional post-processing of the returned value may be needed, see `__builtin_extract_return_addr`.
>
> **The stored representation** of the return address in memory may be different from the address returned by `__builtin_return_address`. For example, on AArch64 the stored address may be mangled with return address signing whereas the address returned by `__builtin_return_address` is not.

What is **the stored representation** of the return address?

> *__builtin_extract_return_addr*:
>
> The address as returned by `__builtin_return_address` may have to be fed through this function to get **the actual encoded address**. For example, on the 31-bit S/390 platform the highest bit has to be masked out, or on SPARC platforms an offset has to be added for the true next instruction to be executed.
>
> If no fixup is needed, this function simply passes through addr.

What is **the actual encoded address**?

Does it mean that `__builtin_return_address` returns address somehow encoded for CPU? And `__builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0))` returns the direct (without any encoding) actual (without any shifts) return address?

If it is so, why someone needs to use `__builtin_return_address` without `__builtin_extract_return_addr`?

---

I just want to find out which function calls my function. I have addresses of all functions that I got using the *nm* utility. Do the addresses returned by `nm` and the addresses returned by `__builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0))` have the same encoding?